# Vim remap only if source file is in LaTeX

Tags: vim, keymapping

I've got a ½ key on my keyboard and sometimes I want to use it when I'm editing LaTeX in Vim to expand to the right expression i.e. `\frac{1}{2}`.

I know I should do something like :

```
inoremap ½ \frac{1}{2}
```

Now, how do I make this work only with LaTeX files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want Fietype specific autocmds:

```
autocmd Filetype tex,latex inoremap ½ \frac{1}{2}
```

Try something like that. This depends on the `Filetype` option being on (see [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27filetype%27)). You can set it with `set Filetype on`

You can also use an autocmd that checks for the filename when reading or creating a new file:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.latex inoremap ½ \frac{1}{2}
```

Also, you should confirm that hitting the 1/2 key on your keyboard actually inputs the 1/2 symbol, otherwise obviously this isn't going to work. Regardless, you can figure out what code the 1/2 key actually inserts by (in insert mode) hitting ctrl-v and then the physical key.

Comment: Adding onto the filetypes, vim usually sees .tex files as "plaintex."  Good answer!

Comment: Good point, I added a bit of clarification about how the Filetype option works

Comment: That still defines a global mapping that will also affect other buffers edited afterwards in the same Vim session. Better add `<buffer>`, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You'll get a buffer-local variant of a mapping via the `<buffer>` modifier.

To define the mapping for all *Tex* buffers, you can use an `:autocmd` on the `FileType` event (`:setlocal filetype?` will tell you the actual filetype):

```
:autocmd Filetype tex inoremap <buffer> ½ \frac{1}{2}
```

But that get's unwieldy as you add mappings and other settings for various filetypes. Better put the command(s) into `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex_mappings.vim`. (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`.)

Comment: This answer correctly uses buffer-local mappings (`<buffer>`) and gives organizational tip on using `ftplugin` directories. I prefer to use the `after` directory personally. For `tex` `FileType`'s use one of the following patterns: `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`, `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex_*.vim`, or `~/.vim/bundle/ftplugin/tex/*.vim`. For more help see `:h after-directory` & `:h ftplugin-name`

Comment: Thanks @PeterRincker! The `after` directory strictly is only necessary if you need to _override_ filetype defaults. Personal customization can be put in either one. You prefer to keep all of your customization in the `after` directory. That's fine. I prefer to only put overrides there, so that I can quickly see where my config differs from the defaults.