# Vim and LaTeX. How to conceal "\ref{name}" as "[name]" in Vim using Syntax Concealing

Tags: regex, vim, syntax, latex

Consider the following text as part of a LaTeX .tex file:

`This is some latex file, with a citation \ref{citationName} which is great`

I would like to use Vim's syntax concealing feature to turn this line into:

`This is some latex file, with a citation [citationName] which is great`

The following search and replace regex expression will turn the first line into the second: `:s/\v\\ref\{(\w+)}/[\1]/`

However, this is a one-time text replacement, and I would like to use vim's syntax conceal feature, such that:

- If the cursor is on the line containing `\ref{name}`, the original text shows up
- If the cursor is NOT on the line containing `\ref{name}`, then such text is replaced (concealed) with `[name]`

I have read through `:help conceal` and `:help syntax`, but I have been utterly unable to solve this issue.

**The question**

How can I use Vim's conceal feature such that I get the behaviour specified above?

**Attempt 1**:
I am confident that I will not be able to use the regex defined above, as it is. However, I can break the problem in two parts:

- Conceal the string `\ref{` (regex: `\\ref\{`) with character `[`
- Conceal the string `}` which is preceeded by `\ref{` (fancy regex: `\v(\\ref\{(w+))@<=}`) with character `]`

Having both regexes which will find the text I want to conceal, and having the characters I want to conceal them with, how can I actually conceal them?

Comment: You might more expert answers on [vi.se]

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `\ref{name}` with `[name]` by placing the following into your `.vimrc`:

```
au VimEnter * syntax region Statement start='\\ref{' end='}' transparent contains=myStart,myEnd
au VimEnter * syntax match myStart '\\ref{\ze\w\+' contained conceal cchar=[
au VimEnter * syntax match myEnd '\(\\ref{\w\+\)\@<=\zs}' contained conceal cchar=]

au VimEnter * hi! link Conceal Statement
au VimEnter * set conceallevel=2
```

Edit: As @D.BenKnoble mentioned this is not the prettiest/smartest way of doing it. You might want to look into [Latex-Suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite.html), or [filetype specific autocommands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985652/vim-remap-only-if-source-file-is-in-latex).

Comment: Those autocommands may be better off as filetype events or even part of an ftplugin